# How to validate select with PHP?

Tags: php, validation, select

How to validate day/month/year select with php? I red some topics about who to validate select with 2-3 or even 5-6 select options. I would know how to validate that kind of select. But in the case of, for exemple, month, there are 32 options. Or in the case of year option, the are 60-70 options. So im interested in whats the optimal way to do select validation when you have so much options?

Comment: You're talking about a `<select>` with loads of `<option>`s right?

Comment: What have you already tried? And where exactly do you see the difference in validating input with 6 or with 60 different options?

Comment: when i use validation for 3-5-7 selct options i usualy use: if(!empty($gender) && $gender != "Male" && $gender != "Female"){
    $error[] = "Gender not valid";
}

Comment: @Kreator: `if (empty($_POST['gender']) || !in_array($_POST['gender'], array('male', 'female'))) { //wrong }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validating selects is fairly trivial.

**Year**

Let's say you have a sequential range of years from 1960-2013.

Your HTML for the selects is:

```
<select name="year">
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    ...
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

So, you know that your year has to fall in the range of 1960 to 2013:

```
$year = (int) $_POST["year"]);

if ($year < 1960 || $year > 2013) {
    $validationPassed = false;
}
```

Simple enough to validate the year.

**Month**

Now that you know what year it is, you can find out if it is a leap year. However, that is only important for a single month, so first let's validate what month they selected:

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="0">January</option>
    ...
    <option value="11">December</option>
</select>
```

Once again, validation of the month is easy. We know it has to be a value between 0 and 11.

```
$month = (int) $_POST["month"];

if ($month < 0 || $month > 11) {
    $validationPassed = false;
}
```

**Day**

Now we know the month and the year. to validate the selected day, we need to check the following criteria:

1. Is it a leap year?
2. Is it the month of the year with the extra day for the leap year? (February).

[For a year to be a leap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm), it has to be divisible by 400, or not divisible by 100 and divisible by 4:

```
function isLeapYear($year) {
    if ($year % 400 == 0)
        return true;
    else if ($year % 100 == 0)
        return false;
    else if ($year % 4 == 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now, we can check if it is a leap year or not. If it is a leap year, then we know we need to allow 1 extra day in February.

We make an array of days in each month:

```
$daysInMonth = array(31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31);
```

Then we get the amount of days in the current month:

```
$monthDays = $daysInMonth[$month];
```

If it is a leap year, we add a day to the total days in the month:

```
if ($month == 1 && isLeapYear($year)) //February
    $monthDays++;
```

Finally, we can validate the day

```
$day = (int) $_POST["day"];

if ($day < 0 || $day > $monthDays) {
    $validationPassed = false;
}
```

Now, all of this is basically encapsulated into the `checkdate()` function that was in the other answer below. So, to use `checkdate()` instead of all the code above, you could simply do the following:

**HTML**
(Note: checkdate() is not zero-based, so we start our days and months at 1 instead of 0.)

```
<form action="myphp.php" method="post">
    <select name="day">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        ...
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>

    <select name="month">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        ...
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>

    <select name="year">
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        ...
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$day = (int) $_POST["day"];
$month = (int) $_POST["month"];
$year = (int) $_POST["year"];

$validationPassed = checkdate($month, $day, $year);
```

Comment: oh man its so simple. almost basics. that realy helps. thank you very much

Comment: It's an underusage of `checkdate()`

Comment: `checkdate()` is actually built to do exactly what I've outlined here. I've basically exposed how `checkdate()` functions internally.

Comment: @crush: "I've basically exposed how" - for what? ;-)

Comment: So he understands how it works. It's always better to know how things work than just to depend on them to work. Maybe he decides he wants to throw an extra wheel into the validation that isn't covered by `checkdate`.

Answer (score 2):

For date it's actually relatively easy - you just use [`checkdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php).

And for the other cases you could check if the value is within an expected range like:

```
if ($val >= min && $val <= max)
```

or, in case you have all the values in an array

```
if (in_array($val, $array_of_valid_values))
```

Comment: can you give me some more detailes about the second code cos im newb in this?

Comment: @Kreator: http://php.net/in_array - check the documentation for every function you don't know before you ask. Nothing wrong in being newbie, but it's not a justification to not checking the manual first

Comment: @zerkms, do you understand that when your new in something you dont know where to look for answer? You can go to php.net and just watch, maybe this can help maybe that will do. Kapish?

Comment: function name or functionname? cos i get many results when i went to that page. specify article or part

Comment: There is a search box at the top of the page on http://www.php.net where you can type your function into and get the documentation.

Comment: i know man how to search. it would be better to specify what should i excactly read?

Comment: Read all of it =]. Mainly the description, and the parameters, though. They usually have examples too which show how to use the functions.

Comment: its easily to say. in my experiance the best way to learn is to see other peoples solutions for some kind of problem and repeat that with changes ofc. during that u can find out about some function that very practical and usefull. again when youre new and if you constantly read php.net instructions youle probably learn comething but less then live examples for sure.

Comment: @Kreator: "the best way to learn is to see other peoples solutions" --- the thing is most people write crappy code, so you just inherit bad solutions and habits. Like with the answer you checked - all the answer may be replaced with a tiny `checkdate` function.

Comment: Bitter much? Yes, `checkdate` should be used. My code is hardly "crappy" or a "bad solution". It simply explains to Kreator how the logic of validating his selects proceeds.

Comment: @crush: it was more about "bad habits" of reinventing the wheel rather than using the built-in and ready to use solutions

Comment: he posted in details how to do what i asked. you gave me 1 function and 2 lines of code. maybe its enough for experienced progremer but for me his detailed code is more understandable. maybe youre code is better  and more elegant. i wouldnt know, for now. i see your reputation, so u probably know what ur talking about.

Comment: @zerkms What if he wants to exclude leap dates or a subset range of years, etc. Not all of that is covered by `checkdate`.

Comment: @crush: "what if" - we're here not to guess. Well, at least me :-) What if he wants to show a youtube video with kittens as a result?